# restart all god tasks

Tags: ruby, god

Here's the description for god's restart command: `restart <task or group name>`. The builtin init script does a kill, followed by a start. Is there really no built-in way to send a restart command to all watches whether they are grouped or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. You have to restart either each group or each individual process.

Comment: There's a guy who tried to code it up as an [event](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-restart-god-when-you-deploy-a-new-release/). But that's too much work for me.

Comment: You could always just group all your watches into a single group. Then just restart that group.

Comment: No, my watches are grouped by logical meaning. If there were hierarchical groupings, then I could do what you proposed.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to restart all watches (it is a hack), but the below should produce the behavior.  It terminates god and all tasks, then restarts god.

```
$ sudo god terminate && sudo /etc/init.d/god start
```

Comment: I know about this, but this won't do a `restart` command on the watches. Instead it will do a `stop` followed by a `start`. A `restart` is usually meant to be a soft restart like reloading configs.

Answer (score 3):

For people reaching there looking for a current solution, please note this feature is now provided in 0.13.3 : if no parameter is given to start / stop / restart, it will be triggered on all watches.